# Qt MySQL for TLS = 1.2

Tags: mysql, qt, tls1.2

I have  an MySQL Server 8.0, which supports connection with TLS =1.2 and higher . I use Qt 5.14.2 and I created an MySQL client. I am not able to connect with my server, I tried with another server which has MySQL 5.7 and it works perfectly. Can I resolve it? I didn't find option to set TLS in QSqlDatabase option. Thanks.

I tried with another server which has MySQL 5.7 and it works perfectly

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Yes,  error : QSqlError("2026", "QMYSQL:Unable to connect", "SSL connection error: unknown error number")

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied ssl dll in exe path?

Comment: Yes, i copied libssl-1_1-x64.dll in the debug and release file but nothing happened, still the error : QSqlError("2026", "QMYSQL:Unable to connect", "SSL connection error: unknown error number")

Comment: there is another dll file called libcrypto.dll check if it's in the same folder

Comment: Yes i put libcrypto.dll too it doesn't work

Comment: I used this : https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases?page=3 nothing works even when i disable ssl from the server side

Comment: is libmysql.dll for mysql 8?

Comment: Yes, it is for mysql 8

Comment: mysql 8 does not support tls 1.1, you need a 1.2 version of dll

Comment: So libssl-1_1-x64.dll doesn't work with mysql 8, i am confused!!!

Comment: try with libssl-1_1-x64.dll latest version

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I tried libssl 1.1.1.7 nothing changes

Comment: try to disable firewall to confirm if the port is not blocked

Comment: Fireware disables port not blocked, i can connect with mysql workbench, with command line too, the problem is here just with qt application and only for mysql 8.0 (connection established well to mysql 5.7 with the same qt application)